# The hierarchy of the type Classe is inconsistent

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have a class that implements an abstract class. The abstract class is in another package of my project. Added the package where the class is abstract by Configure build path/Project. In class that implements is accusing the following error: The hierarchy of the type class is inconsistent

Have I to add this package somewhere else?

Thank you!

Comment: Show some code or something. Your explanation is somewhat less than coherent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse compilation error: The hierarchy of the type 'Class name' is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520090/eclipse-compilation-error-the-hierarchy-of-the-type-class-name-is-inconsisten)

Answer (score 37):

These errors happened because some interface/class in the hierarchy cannot be resolved.
For example: the error is in your class - class X, X inherits Y, and in turn, Y inherits Z. However, the compiler cannot resolve z (in above error), because z is belong to a library that is not included.
Therefore, you have to add package containing z to the classpath/ or project's Java Build Path (if you are using eclipse).
hope it may help.

Comment: +1 for this answer thanks. I just had this error and would like to add: This can also happen if class Z is your own class, but has a Syntax error. So class Z cannot be compiled. In my case class Z could not be compiled because it used a Java 7 method, but I downgraded the environment to Java 6.

Answer (score 8):

Go to the Project Explorer.

1. Right Click on your Project
2. Build Path
3. Configure Build Path
4. Remove JRE System Library
5. Click on Add Library
6. Add JRE System Library
7. Click on Next and then Finish

The errors will be resolved.

Comment: This works to me, but, I didn't remove and add the 'JRE System Library' because, in my case, the problem was in other JAR library. I have created the project with 'maven-eclipse-plugin' (2.10) and removing and add the suspect library really works in eclipse Luna.

Answer (score 6):

This means you have made an incompatible change in a super class but haven't recompiled it.

I suggest you use a build system like Maven or Ant and/or use an IDE to build all your code.

Comment: I downloaded the SVN version and the project is already using Ant, will I need to configure something to the class is visible?

Comment: You need to make sure everything is re-compiled. I would expect that when you try to do this you will see a compilation error which will explain your problem.

Comment: Not blaming anything. Only accuses the code itself:"The hierarchy of the type BDIGenericGeneratorEvent is inconsistent"

Comment: That means this class was not compiled with the version you have for a super class.

Comment: The class exists in the imported package (Java Build Path / Projects), but as it was not imported the class.

Comment: The error means the versions of the two classes are incompatible. The class exists and must be imported correctly or it won't have this error.

Comment: When trying to run some execeções appears: ERROR [MainDeployer] Could not start deployment: file:/C:/ambiente/jboss-4.0.4.GA/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp13011evs-portab.ear-contents/ev5-17Web.war
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Error during deploy; - nested throwable: (javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: comp not bound)

Answer (score 3):

I was facing this issue in one of My RCP application.

Cause: I was not added core plugin **`org.eclipse.core.runtime`** in dependancy section of Manifest file.
When I have added this dependency jar issue has been resolved.

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 2):

That means class which implemented by you has reference to the interface or class which again references some other classes or interfaces in other libraries and those are not available.

Answer (score 1):

springframework.aop jar is  depends on aopalliance.jar  add it to your class path it will resolve ur problm hope it works cos i was facing same prob I added dependent jar so it resolved

Answer (score 0):

```
right click your project ,Properties- java build path- source- include all the cs file source(it may inherit the files) and sync.
```

this worked for me and correctly.

Comment: This advice depends on the IDE used. @Deb might not be using the same one that you are.

Comment: yeah that also corect.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem when tried to use some class from a plugin project in another one. 
I had something like myClass extends pp1Class - here i had the error, pp1Class plugin was added as a dependency. pp1Class extends pp2Class - which was a dependency in pp1 (plugin proj1) but not in my plugin. What i did was go to pp1 and where you have defined the dependency to pp2, click properties and check the "Reexport this dependency" (this is in the MANIFEST.MF).
This should solve the problem, it solved mine.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this error is, one of your base classes implements an interface which is in an external library, and your .classpath file is kept on a source control system (therefore readonly).

For instance, your ClassB extends ClassA and ClassA implements InterfaceA which is in LibraryA.jar. ClassA is in ProjectA, ClassB is in ProjectB. ProjectA .classpath file is readonly.

Here you have to export the LibraryA.jar from your ProjectA. But I guess due to an Eclipse bug, when a new team mate connects these projects (or occasionally when you prepare another workspace), he gets this type hierarchy error. Only way to solve this problem is to check-out .classpath file in ProjectA, remove and re-add a library (does not have to be LibraryA.jar). This operation somehow resolves the error.

Answer (score 0):

In the Eclipse, OSGi environment, the required package can be added to the MANIFEST.MF-> Dependencies tab -> Imported packages. This will solve the issue. Or the plugin which contains the class can be added to the Required Plugin-ins

Answer (score 0):

I also face this issue in my `maven` project using with `Eclipse oxygen.1a` IDE,

> The hierarchy of the type MyClassName is inconsistent

Error showing on class name level,

thereafter I took complete svn update from repository and later `Maven -> Update Project` and later `Project Refresh`.

The error was gone...

As per my understanding, this were happening due to unmanaged project version.

Answer (score 0):

I actually added all the related jars and interfaces in build path but still I was facing the error so later someone suggested me to add the j2ee.jar in build path and my error just went away.

Answer (score -1):

> The hierarchy of the type A is inconsistent

The above error is mainly because of Some jars missing in the classpath
eg: I was trying to implement an interface "MethodBeforeAdvice"

Here MethodBeforeAdvice implements BeforeAdvice and these two interfaces were present in one jar file called "Spring-aop-4.2.5.Release.jar"

But "BeforeAdvice" interface implements an interface "Advice" which was present in some other jar "aop-alliance-1.0.0.jar" which was not present in my class-path