# Modifying the TestCase.class present inside junit.framwork gives "The hierarchy of the type 'classname' is inconsistent" error in the subclass

Tags: java, junit

I have added a new variable in the TestCase.class file present inside junit.framework package inside junit.jar(4.11). After adding the variable and replacing the old TestCase.class file with modified one, i am getting the error "The hierarchy of the type 'classname' is inconsistent" in the class declaration where i am extending the TestCase class. Below is the code.

```
public class Junit_Test extends TestCase {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init(){
        System.out.println("Executing beforeclass annotation");
    }

}
```

the TestCase.class modification:

```
public abstract class TestCase extends Assert implements Test {
    /**
     * the name of the test case
     */
    private String fName;
    private String fDesc;      //added this variable
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error happen when jre jar file are not in build path. Add jar file to the build path and try to run again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ricky2527, but my buildpath(properties->java build path->library) already contains the junit 4.11 jar and jre jar as well as in run configuration under user entries the junit jar is present.                               Let me explain briefly what i am trying to do here. I have a class which contains junit tests and this class exetnds TestCase class. When i run it using a batchrunner it run fines. Then i am creating a new variable in TestCase.class and replacing it in the existing junit jar. That is when the "The hierarchy.." error is coming in the junit test class.

Comment: Then I think this error come because of you made change in super class. Look at this similar problem, hope it helps you.
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179824/the-hierarchy-of-the-type-classe-is-inconsistent

Comment: I found it...such a big pain...let me explain you what was happening. The changes i was doing in, TestCase.java was not the actual source code of the TestCase.class. The source attached to TestCase.class was different what actually the code was in TestCase.class. So when i was doing changes to the TestCase.java, compiling it and replacing the TestCase.class, the new TestCase.class was not fitting and i was getting the error "...inconsistent".

Comment: I found the actual code of TestCase.class(by pressing F3 on the TestCase class name present in my Junit test case) then i made the changes to actual code, compiled it and replaced  it..then the error went away. Thanks for your help @ricky2527