# Cannot extend CDT CEditor: "The hierarchy of the type '' is inconsistent"

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

When trying to write a class that extends I get the error message:

> The hierarchy of the type 'MYEditor' is inconsistent.

```
import org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.editor.CEditor;

public class MYEditor extends CEditor {

}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12179888/2013672) says:

> These errors happened because some interface/class in the hierarchy
>   cannot be resolved.

This indicates that eclipse cannot find a class in the hierarchy. But when I use the class in my plugin.xml, it works. I am using it like this:

```
<editor
    class="org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.editor.CEditor"
    contributorClass="org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.editor.CEditorActionContributor"
    default="true"
    filenames="*.grasp, *.c"
    icon="icons/small.png"
    id="de.blub.ide.myeditor"
    name="My Editor">
</editor>
```

This works, but lacks a few features that I need for my plugin. That's why I want to use a class that inherits from CEditor.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29864443/2013672) didn't work, to (remove and add JRE System Library).

I've also read that the jar file needs to be put in the Classpath section of the plugin.xml. But the "Add" and "New" Buttons don't provide a way to chose an external jar file. I can manually copy that jar file from "~/.p2/pool/plugins" into my projects lib folder, but that didn't help.

Comment: Note that extending **internal** classes is against the rules - [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html). Internal classes may be changed without warning.

Comment: So what can I do to add functionality to CEditor?

Comment: Look at the extension points defined for the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug-ins reference code in other plug-ins by including the other plug-in in their dependencies list. This is the `Require-Bundle` entry in the plug-in's MANIFEST.MF.

In the MANIFEST.MF/plugin.xml/build.properties editor you can set the dependencies in the 'Required Plug-ins' section on the 'Dependencies' page.

Do not copy plugin jars, do not put plugin jars in the Java Build Path.

But note that extending **internal** classes is against the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html). Internal classes may change without warning and may be different in older releases.

The [CDT Plug-in Programmer's Guide](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/index.jsp?nav=%2F15) covers the official APIs for Eclipse CDT.

Comment: `org.eclipse.cdt.ui` is already listed in the "Required Plug-ins" section. That alone doesn't seem to allow me to extend the CEditor.

Comment: Assuming that is the plugin containing the editor there should not be anything else required provided your plugin is set up properly.

Comment: What is it that could possibly be set up inproperly?

Comment: Diagnosing setup and build problems is very difficult remotely. Maybe if you show us the contents of the plugin's `.project`, `.classpath`, `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, `plugin.xml` and `build.properties` files someone might see something.

Comment: I don't see why that's necessary since everyting else works. `build.properties` has no entry that affects cdt. The MANIFEST.MF has an entry for `org.eclipse.cdt.ui` in the "Require-Bundle" section. Maybe it's not a good idea to extend CEditor. It seems that it's not intended anyway.