# The hierarchy of the type XXXX is inconsistent

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm getting sick with this compilation error, every time i try to extend a vaadin class or implement vaadin interaface :

Here's the error :

```
- The hierarchy of the type ButtonPanel is inconsistent
```

Here's an example :

```
package com.kopiright.vkopi.lib.ui.vaadin.base;

import com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalLayout;

 public class ButtonPanel extends HorizontalLayout {

 }
```

I'm using Vaadin-server 7.0.0

Comment: How are you compiling it?

Comment: Eclipse gives me the error in red color

Comment: Yeah, that's not actually a compilation error. It's just eclipse being stupid. It'll compile fine.

Comment: ah ok i didn't compile it yet , thank you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse compilation error: The hierarchy of the type 'Class name' is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520090/eclipse-compilation-error-the-hierarchy-of-the-type-class-name-is-inconsisten)