# Spring Boot 2 Jersey Implementation not working

Tags: spring-boot, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am using Spring Boot 2 to implement REST implementation using Jersey. I am not able to register the Resource class as part of Jersey implementation. I am getting a compiler error.

Error:

compiler error: The hierarchy of type JerseyConfig is inconsistent.

**Service/Resource Code:**

```
@Service
@Path("/api/v1")
public class PersonResource {

    private final PersonRepository personRepo;

    @Autowired
    public PersonResource(PersonRepository personRepo) {
        this.personRepo = personRepo;
    }


    @GET
    @Path( "/persons")
    @Produces("application/json")

    public List<Person> getAllPerson(){
        List<Person> persons = personRepo.findAll();
        return persons;

    }

    @GET
    @Path( "/persons/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response findPersonById(@PathParam("id") String id) throws NumberFormatException, Exception{
        Person person = personRepo.findById(Long.valueOf(id)).orElseThrow( () -> new Exception("Unable to find a person with id: " + id));
        return Response.ok(person, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();

}
```

**Configuration:**

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.demo.rest.PersonResource;

@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {

        register(PersonResource.class);
    }
}
```

**Maven Dependency:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am not sure what I am missing in terms of configuration. Any pointers to help solve this problem is appreciated.

GitHub code link:

https://github.com/sureshpec04/jersey-rest-demo

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket on `findPersonById`. I don't see any other compilation errors. Also instead of `@Service`, you should use `@Component` on your resource class (though this is not a compilation error). Also remove the `javax.ws.rs-api` dependency. It's not needed. It's already pulled in by Jersey (you are using the wrong version)

Comment: Also check [Eclipse compilation error: The hierarchy of the type 'Class name' is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8520090/2587435)

Comment: @Paul - If I remove the javax.ws.rs-api dependency GET, Path, Response are not getting resolved. Should it be resolved by jersey starters dependency?

Comment: Then you have a problem with your environment. Jersey should pull it in. Make sure you have the Spring boot parent pom set. Try to clean your workspace and local Maven repository. And check out that link above.

Comment: @Paul - I will create a new project from scratch and update you.

Comment: I created the project from scratch and still did not work. code is available in Git Hub: https://github.com/sureshpec04/jersey-rest-demo

Comment: Did you try to delete your whole (maven) local repo yet? Sometimes it will get corrupted, leading to strange errors. Only way to fix it is to delete the whole thing.

Comment: Your project is fine. I have no problem with it. I think if you do like I said and delete your local maven repository and let it download all new dependencies, it should work.

Comment: @Paul - As you mentioned, cleaning up my maven repository solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rename the `JerseyConfig` class name to `AppConfig` or SomethingConfig.

Comment: Still no luck. Updated my question with github link.

Comment: i'm not getting error RestConfig1. Jars might be corrupted . Try to clean your maven repository and run your project

Comment: cleaning up my maven repository fixed the issue. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Rename `JerseyConfig`  to `YourCustomNameConfig` and going `pom.xml` click right maven->reimport or rebuild .