# How to resolve : "The hierarchy of the type StepsCode is inconsistent" problem

Tags: java, maven, testing, cucumber-jvm

How to use a method of class of project A in a class on project B, all projects are maven projects and it's an existing projects with lot of packages and classes , it's for a cucumber test projects, I have the application with lot of projects and packages, and i need to make test with cucumber on it, so i tried to create a new maven project and when I tried to call a function from one of the existing project, it says : " The hierarchy of the type StepsCode is inconsistent"

All the configuration is done, i refresh all projects and it still don't work .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse compilation error: The hierarchy of the type 'Class name' is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520090/eclipse-compilation-error-the-hierarchy-of-the-type-class-name-is-inconsisten)

Comment: problem solved, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first check if the methods and the classes you are going to use are public, then you can add the projects, with the methods you need to call, as dependency in the pom.xml file.

Comment: problem solved, thank you !